# Dell OMSA Predicted Failure column is missing

Tags: dell-poweredge, dell-perc, dell-openmanage

I have a **PowerEdge R210** II with OMSA 8.4 installed.
When I go to check the HD status, under Storage>**PERC H200** Adapter>Virtual Disks, I have the two (dell) HD but only with the columns up to "Revision", the most important one, "**Predicted Failure**", is missing.

Should I have to enable something?

Additional Info:
I have windows2012R2, iDrac6, and one disk is currently under rebuild due to a failure this morning. HDs have been manufactured in 2012 and 2013.

HDs are two Dell/**Seagate Cheetah** ST3600057SS

Answer (score 1):

The Predicted Failure column is hidden by default unless at least one of the hard drives is currently in predictive failure state. This doesn't seem to be specifically mentioned in the official documentation for OMSA, but I've noticed the change in layout when replacing a predictive failure disk.

If you want to make sure the other drive is healthy, you can boot to the F10 menu after the rebuild completes and run hardware diagnostics.